# Convert sub-type to super-type

Tags: java

I have a abstract super class A, and a subclass B that extends this class.

```
public abstract class A {

}

public class B extends A {


}
```

I have a method that returns type A, but object B

```
public A fetchType() {
    A a = new B();
    return a;

}
```

When I call the fetchType method, I want to actually get object A. In this case, I might have to cast B to A so I get A. How can I do that?

Comment: I don't understand. The return type is `A`. A `B` is an `A`. No cast is needed.

Comment: I know B is an A, but I actually want to get object A. Not B.

Comment: There is no object of runtime type `A`. You've done `new B()`. That returns a reference to a new object of runtime type `B`.

Comment: This is impossible. You cannot create an object `A` since it is abstract.

Comment: Wait, wait wait. Do you want the type `A` (like a `Class` object?) or a value of type `A`?

Comment: Value of type A is B. I want to be able to cast B to A, so I get A.

Comment: _Be able to cast B to A_. You can **always** cast a value of a subtype to a value of a supertype, but you **never** need to.

Comment: Will casting subtype to supertype give me supertype?

Comment: Please define what you mean by _give me supertype_. What do you think a type is? What do you think a value is?

Comment: Also, what do you think _casting_ does?

Comment: Type is reference. Value is the object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot create an object if the type is abstract.

Here class `A` is abstract class, which means you will NEVER be able to create object `A`.

This is not allowed: `A a = new A();`